# What does the meaning of "down to a level"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I see this in here :  http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/0/fa469462-1a32-11e3-93e8-00144feab7de.html#axzz2eXhIUa4M

> “It’s very much the next frontier,” said Renée James, Intel’s president. “It takes us down to a level we haven’t been at before.” After reacting late to the touchscreen mobile device markets, “we are very committed to not missing the next one,” she added.

And I want to know what' the meaning.
Thank you.

Comment: It's referring to computer chips with a smaller size. The New Level refers to a New Generation of smaller chips. There's a good introduction here: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=microprocessor-computer-chip

Comment: so in this artical,is it a positive word?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I understand your question. Often falling to a low level is a bad thing. In this case it's an advancement in technology. Smaller more efficient computer chips.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a stab at suggesting that they are talking about the level of physical dimensions with which they are working, in that these new chips are built at a lower level of size for their component transitiors, gates, etc. that preceding chips.

That's as much based on understanding of how breakthroughs in microchip technology is often dicussed as anything else though, it is not clear from the article on its own.